# Failed to load module script because of a disallowed MIME type

Tags: javascript, import, module, mime-types

Consider the following file structure and content:

```
js
└─ test
    ├─ modules
    │  └─ math.mjs
    └─ main.mjs
```

<sub>**math.mjs:**</sub>

```
export function square(v) { return v * v; }
```

<sub>**main.mjs:**</sub>

```
import { square } from './modules/math.mjs';
console.log(square(2));
```

---

On a simple page at `http://server.local/module-test` (through Apache web server), I'm trying to load the `main.mjs`:

```
<script type="module" src="http://server.local/js/test/main.mjs"></script>
```

but the browsers keep complaining about the MIME type, for example:

> *Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

I've tried other relative-references (through `/`, `./` and `../`) on the `import` statement  to no avail!

So, what I've missed to have it working?

Comment: Configure the server to serve `.mjs` files with an appropriate javascript MIME type, or simply try using `.js` file extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the conditions for a module to be loaded by the browser is that the server serves the module with a MIME type of `application/javascript` (or other appropriate MIME type depending on language and browser support; there's a new type `javascript/esm` for javascript modules that has mixed support). This means configuring the server provide a response header that includes at least `Content-Type: application/javascript` for javascript modules (or javascript in general).

From the error you're getting, it seems your server is either providing an empty `Content-Type` header or not providing it at all. This usually happens when trying to load modules from a `file://` url, without a server, but can happen with a mis-configured server.

It's likely that the file extension `.mjs` is unrecognized by the server so its unable to serve it with the right MIME type.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a web server at my hoster. ".mjs" is apparently not yet supported by many web servers. See also: https://github.com/GeoffreyBooth/js-mjs-mime-type-test

So, if the server does not respond with correct MIME-Type for `.mjs` or other files, you may be able to add this Type in the .htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript mjs
</IfModule>
```

That solved the problem for me.